# How to add our own created framework into iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I want to add my own framework into my app so can any one tell me the step by step process to how to add our own framework in iphone sdk

Thank you to All...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to include your framework in the new project as a static library. I do this with cocos2d, as illustrated in [this tutorial](http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/), and it works out wonderfully.

The Cocos2d project (or, in your case, the project that builds your framework) has a static library target. As per the tutorial, I've included this in my main project, and added the static library target as a Direct Dependency, so my app builds the static library up every time I build my app.

If you don't need this sort of control, or if the framework doesn't change very much, you might simply build your project as a static library and add the file to your project without any of the linking described above.

Answer (score 0):

No can do. Apple does not allow creating and distributing third party frameworks for iOS.

The best you can do is offer a static libs, or source files for other apps to link against and ship as part of their code.